# A disk read error occured when reading bootable USB

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, boot, usb

I'm trying to install Windows 7 from a bootable USB stick. My other laptop read it properly. However when I try to boot from a defective laptop, it tells me:

> A disk read error occured. Press Ctrl
>   + Alt + Del to restart.

I have Windows XP on the laptop: it reaches the Windows boot screen, tries to load Windows then restarts. What can I do? I can't boot Windows 7, so I can't run chkdsk or anything.

Comment: Not sure if you are trying to install Windows 7 or repair the XP installation? Please clarify exactly what you are trying to accomplish, use the edit feature to modify your question.

Comment: I'm trying to install windows 7 from a USB boot stick.\

Comment: It was your second paragraph that had me wondering. Will it boot from any other bootable usb device? Did you try all the usb ports?

Comment: Do you get the same disk read error when you boot from the hard drive?, if you do, it may not be trying to boot from USB at all.

Comment: @Moab I tried all USB ports. I did not get any error for trying to boot from the hard drive. It loaded up the windows xp bot screen.

Comment: It must be some kind of bios USB limitation, have you checked for any bios settings regarding USB, like enable/disable legacy support?

Comment: Just turned off support for legacy USB and now it doesn't find the usb stick when I choose to select boot device.

Comment: All that is left is to update (flash) the bios to the latest version if it is not already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes an USB stick error happens when having a lot of files in root folder. If there's more stuff than actually the files needed to make the Windows install, try to move them to some safe device/computer.

Some times is the file system of the USB and/or operative system. USB sticks are often FAT 32, or FAT 16. In some cases people install Windows XP in FAT 32. I guess your Windows 7 is in NTFS file system, as usual. Might happen some issue related to this.

Did you check that in the defective laptop BIOS menu, you have USB listed in boot sequence/options ? You might have it configured differently or laptop BIOS not supporting USB boot at all.

Comment: So what I did was to move the USB drive to be booted at the top of the list. It gives this error when I try to select it in the boot device manager.

Comment: @ShawnMclean And what exactly solved your problem?

Comment: @Thomas the first sentence. That bios at the time allowed me to reorder the boot devices instead of selecting them.

Answer (score 2):

If the same USB drive works in another system, then the problem must lie with  your XP system. You could try a BIOS update if there is a later version available.
If that does not help, make an Easy2Boot v1.91B USB drive and add the Win7 ISO to it (_ISO\WINDOWS\WIN7 folder). 
Do NOT set the boot order to boot from the USB drive - instead use a F key (e.g. F8, F10, F11, F12 or whatever) to invoke the BIOS Boot Selection pop-up box and then select the USB drive as the boot drive.
Use a USB 2 port.
As soon as it starts to boot, immediately press and hold down the SHIFT key. This will install the grub4dos USB 2 driver which may be less buggy than your BIOS's USB driver. You should see a message about 1 Device found (0x80). Then select the Windows Install - Win7 menu and try installing Windows 7 usual.

Comment: This definitely sorted me out. Tried: "Rufus", "Universal USB installer", "MS Windows USB DVD Tool", "Windows 7 USB edition", "WinToUSB", and couple other methods. None worked except this. #OldPCProblems